# In $\Delta ABC$ if $(\sqrt{3}-1)a=2b$, $A=3B$, then find $C$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> In $\Delta ABC$ if $(\sqrt{3}-1)a=2b$, $A=3B$, then find $C$

**My Attempt**
$$
b=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{2}a\quad\& \quad \frac{A-B}{2}=B\quad\&\quad\frac{A+B}{2}=2B\\\frac{a-b}{a+b}=\frac{\tan\frac{A-B}{2}}{\tan\frac{A+B}{2}}\implies \frac{3-\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}+1}=\frac{\tan B}{\tan 2B}=\frac{1-\tan^2B}{2}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the standard notation by law of sines we obtain:
$$\frac{\sin\beta}{\sin3\beta}=\frac{\sqrt3-1}{2}$$ or
$$\frac{1}{3-4\sin^2\beta}=\frac{\sqrt3-1}{2}$$ or
$$3-4\sin^2\beta=\sqrt3+1$$ or
$$8\sin^2\beta=(\sqrt3-1)^2$$ or
$$\sin\beta=\frac{\sqrt3-1}{2\sqrt2},$$ which gives $$\beta=15^{\circ}.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: I would've gone with $ 2 - 4\sin^2 B = \sqrt{3} \implies 2\cos(2B) = \sqrt{3} \implies 2B = 30^\circ $, since $\sin 15^\circ$ isn't really well-known

Comment: @Dylan Or maybe $2\beta=330^{\circ}$, which is $\beta=165^{\circ},$ which is impossible. I think everyone, which solved during his life one ore maybe two problems, knows what is it $\sin15^{\circ}.$

Comment: Well yes, there would be 2 solutions, one of which will be ruled out since $3B < 180^\circ$. I've never had to solve for $\sin 15^\circ$ so I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: @Dylan There are also $\sin18^{\circ}$, $\cos36^{\circ}$, $\tan15^{\circ}$, $\tan22.5^{\circ}$ and more. It's better to know it.

Comment: I suppose you're right, but I don't think it should be considered common knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

$$2\sin B=(\sqrt3-1)\sin3B=(...)(\sin B)(3-4\sin^2B)$$

As $\sin B>0,$ $$\sin^2B=\dfrac{2-\sqrt3}4$$

$$\cos2B=1-\dfrac{2-\sqrt3}2=\cos30^\circ$$

$0<2B<360^\circ,2B=360^\circ n\pm30^\circ$ for some integer $n$

$\implies2B=30^\circ$